# NGINX rewrite location without changing url

Tags: nginx

When visiting /abc/sitemap.xml I'd like to display the content of `/abc/sitemap?output=xml` **without changing the url**.

Currently, it shows the right content, but changes the url to /abc/sitemap?output=xml instead of keeping /abc/sitemap.xml, and here is my config.

```
location /abc/sitemap.xml {
    rewrite ^ /abc/sitemap?output=xml;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about a [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html):

```
location /abc/sitemap.xml {
    proxy_pass http://$host/abc/sitemap?output=xml;
}
```

**Note:** use `HTTP` or `HTTPS` depending on your SSL configurations.